# How to match number "start with" through query sqlite

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

Is there any way to match the query, for example, I want to search my number against the rules **(table name)** through query.
I want to match the number which starts with  `"333"` **rules** ......... 
1)3322323

Here is my  query

```
SELECT * FROM demo where rules like '33322323';
```

I want above query return **true**. because it matches with my rule.

Below is my table.

```
  id    | rules
............... 
   1    |  333
   2    |  22
   3    |  442
```

I  have sample data  **1) 33331235, 2) 2354545 3) 4424545454  4) 22343434**

**Case 1 (matching data   1) 33331235)**

Suppose I want to check my **33331235** with my rules table   so my sample data match with my

> **row 1** which is 333, because of my data start with 333..... it should return true because of it matched.

**Case 2 (matching data   2) 2354545)**

Suppose I want to check my **2354545** with my rules table   so my sample data does not  match with my

> Any row because my no rule applies on it..... it should return true because of it matched.

**Case 3 (matching data   1) 4424545454)**

Suppose I want to check my **4424545454** with my rules table   so my sample data match with my

> **row 1** which is 442, because of my data start with 442..... it should return true because of it matched.

**Solved.**

I solved this with the help of **Forpas** I used this query to match number start with

```
SELECT * FROM demo where '333434334 like rules ||'%';
```

The number **at the end of the string** when I use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM demo where '333434334' like '%' || rules;
```

The number **anywhere** in the string then I use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM demo where '333434334' like '%' || rules ||'%';
```

Comment: Try `Where rules like '333%'` . If I understood correctly .

Comment: @ADM I update the question home will understand my scenario

Comment: @Amkhan post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the operator `LIKE`. 
You have tagged your question with both **MySQL** and **SQLite**. 
For **MySQL**:

```
SELECT * FROM demo where '33322323' like concat(rules, '%');
```

For **SQLite**:

```
SELECT * FROM demo where '33322323' like rules || '%';
```

The above code will return all rows where the `rules` column value is the starting chars of `33322323`.

Comment: Thank you, bro, I solved this I use this in my case  I am matching  number start with rules  SELECT * FROM demo where '333434334 like  rules ||'%';

Comment: This is incorrect if `rules` contains '%' or '_' .

Comment: @mpartel check the OP's sample data. The column `rules` contains integer values.