How to get data from the database in app_commands.Choice?
Get name list and put in app_commands.Choice
I want to make sure that when I enter /a, it displays a list that it will receive from the music.db database. At the moment he is like this
click
I need to collapse a list of titles that will be received from the music.db database. An example of what it looks like
click
And also when there is a large list of names, you need to do a search, as shown in the example, so as not to search for the desired name in a large list.
If you need more details, write. I use the pycord "voice" library as well as disnake
Database creation
conn = sqlite3.connect('music.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS music
                (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, path TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

conn.close()

Command code
@commands.slash_command(name="a", description="Добавить звук")
    async def a(self, ctx, название = discord.Option(str)):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('music.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT path FROM music WHERE name = ?", (название,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            path = result[0]
            if ctx.author.voice:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
                voice_client = await channel.connect()
                voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda e: print(f'Звук воспроизведен {название}'))
                emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Звук', colour = discord.Color.green() )
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
                emb.set_footer(text = f'Вы запустили звук')
                await ctx.respond(embed=emb)  
                await ctx.delete(delay=10)

                while voice_client.is_playing():
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)

                await voice_client.disconnect()
            else:
                emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Звук', colour = discord.Color.red() )
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
                emb.set_footer(text = f'Вы не подключены к голосовому каналу. ')
                await ctx.respond(embed=emb)  
                await ctx.delete(delay=10)
        else:
            emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Звук', colour = discord.Color.red() )
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            emb.set_footer(text = f'Аудиофайл с таким названием не найден.')
            await ctx.respond(embed=emb)  
            await ctx.delete(delay=10)

        conn.close()


Step one: Creating the database (you probably already have this)
Because you're using sqllite3, this makes this super simple.
Below, I've created a simple database structure that I'll use to search basic paths just like the music paths you already provided:
music = [('beans', 'bean_path'), ('potatoes', 'potato_path'), ('test', 'testpath'), ('test1', 'testpath1'), ('testing', 'testpath2')]

for name_ in music:
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO music VALUES (?, ?)""", (name_[0], name_[1]))
    conn.commit()

This code creates the following databsae which we'll use later in the autoselect features of Py-cord:

Step two: The parameter
In Py-cord, option parameters in slash commands can have autocomplete (source below). The docs say this:

The autocomplete handler for the option. Accepts a callable (sync or async) that takes a single argument of AutocompleteContext. The callable must return an iterable of str or OptionChoice. Alternatively, discord.utils.basic_autocomplete() may be used in place of the callable.

For this example, I used an asynchronous handler for this autocomplete option:
def autocomplete(auto_text):
    # Note: You closed the con earlier, but you didn't have to do that
    cur_execution = cursor.execute("SELECT path FROM music WHERE name like ? || '%'", (auto_text.value,))  # Get the music from the db
    # See more about the like operator here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207123/how-to-match-number-start-with-through-query-sqlite
    options = []
    for name in cur_execution.fetchall():  # get all values
        options.append(discord.OptionChoice(name=name[0]))
    if not options:  # if options is empty
        cur_execution = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM music")  # Fetch all music because we have no options
        for name in cur_execution.fetchall():
            options.append(discord.OptionChoice(name=name[0]))
    return options

After making the function, we can tie this back to the parameter in the slash command:
@bot.slash_command()
async def get_from_database(ctx, name: discord.Option(str, autocomplete=autocomplete)):  # name autocompetes to the autocomplete function
    await ctx.respond(name)

Final results
Below is what it should look like when you don't have anything typed:

Below is what happens when you type part of it out:

Sources:

discord.Option.Autocomplete
discord.Option

